# What would make an alternator produce flutuating voltage

Tags: alternator, seat

The car is a 2013 Seat Mii with start/stop functionality.

The alternator is faulty as the output (measured at the alternator on an oscilloscope after the regulator) fluctuates between 3V and 14.5V in a random pattern. It should stay constant at 14.5V.

I've killed my battery due to undercharging through several weeks.

Is it the regulator (built into the alternator) or the alternator itself which is faulty ? Is it repairable ?

The alternator is a  110A BOSCH item with part number 04C 903 023D

Comment: poor signal from ecu?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Yes is is repairable but we have no idea what you skills are in repairing an alternator, best solution is to replace the alternator.

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the plug and run the engine at 2500 rpm?

Comment: @SolarMike what does the ecu have to do with this ?

Comment: Some cars have a signal from ecu to the alternator to control power delivery at various times...

Comment: @Moab I will be replacing it, just wanted to get a direction on fault finding on the old one,

Comment: @Ben, there is no room on these tiny cars to unplug anything, so i'll have to dismantle before I can test this (but by that time, I'll be replacing the alterator)